# Mockito when...return clauses inside setUp method

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I would like to ask if it is a good practice in a test class to use inside the setUp method (@Before annotated) the mockito clauses 'when' and 'return', although that sentence is used in every tests in this class.

Example:

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
    when(...).thenReturn(...)
}
```

Comment: Yes, if the mocks are used in every test, then factoring them out makes the tests cleaner.

Comment: We (or I) can't tell without knowing anything about *what* your are testing and what *tests* there are. Keep in mind that a best practice is an orientation in the first place, it's not a rule. It's telling you that by "best by test" something is great under given circumstances. But your case could be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If the behavior is needed by every test, it would be a good idea to put it in an `@Before`, to eliminate duplication.
2. If the behavior is need by some tests, it would be a good idea to put it into a `setupFoo(...)` or `fooMocking(...)` helper method, to eliminate duplication.

Good luck!